# how can i use the OR operator in sugar orm?

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

how can i use the OR operator to query my database with sugar ORM.
i want to retrieve all data that has zero in its selling price or cost price.

here is my code but it's not working, instead it will select all data in the database

```
 public static List<Inventory> cost_price()
{
    return Inventory.findWithQuery(Inventory.class, "select * from inventory where "+NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("cCostPrice")+" = 0 OR "+NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("bCostPrice")+" = 0");


}
```

what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the query builder. Maybe something like this will work :

```
Select.from(Inventory.class).whereOr(Condition.prop("cCostPrice").eq(0),Condition.prop("bCostPrice").eq("0")).list();
```